# changing php function calling URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've already search for an answer here, but couldn't find an exact answer.

I've got a php application (it uses CodeIgniter) which is connected to our companys Management Database. The application provides information out of the database in xml form so that our internal mediawiki's can receive those and build Info-Boxes (as example) out of them.

I have the following link to my data in xml format:
    `https://example.com/controller/function/databaseID/short_name` or 
    `https://example.com/App/makeInfoBox/258/Applicationname`

which contains Infromation as following:

```
-<infobox>
<id>258</id>
<short_name>Applicationname</short_name>
<long_name>Long Applicationname</long_name>
<app_number>334</app_number>
<status>End of life</status>
...
</infobox>`
```

I now want mod_rewrite to change the url to:

`https://example.com/appInfoBox.xml?id=258&short_name=Applicationname`

I've got something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)\&short_name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^appInfoBox\.xml$ App/makeInfoBox/%1/%2
```

I'm really not good in mod_rewrite and this code I got is based on a older version of a used .htaccess file.

Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to redirect the current URL `https://example.com/App/makeInfoBox/258/Applicationname` to a new URL  `https://example.com/appInfoBox.xml?id=258&short_name=Applicationname` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must capture the relevant parts of the request `(...)` and use this in the substitution `$...`

```
RewriteRule ^App/makeInfoBox/(.+?)/(.+)$ /appInfoBox.xml?id=$1&short_name=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following directives in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/App/makeInfoBox/([0-9]+)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appInfoBox.xml?id=%1&short_name=%2 [QSA,R=302]
```

The .htaccess file should be present in the root folder of example.com.

The RewriteCond directive will check whether the request matches the pattern `/App/makeInfoBox/(any-number)/(any-number-of-characters)`.

IF this is true the RewriteRule directive will map the request to `example.com/appInfoBox.xml?id=(any-number)&short_name=(any-number-of-characters)` using the `QSA` flag.

The `R=302` flag will cause an external redirect and the end user will be able to see the new URL with query string on the browser.

If you don't want to display the URL with query string to end users, just remove the `R=302` flag.

Using your example, now if you will access https://example.com/App/makeInfoBox/258/Applicationname it will redirect to https://example.com/appInfoBox.xml?id=258&short_name=Applicationname

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Reading my question I noticed that I made something up. I need the opposite thing, so the URL `https://example.com/appInfoBox.xml?id=258&short_name=Applicationname` needs to be rewritten by mod_rewrite to `https://example.com/App/makeInfoBox/258/Applicationname` so that the server can execute the php function with the given ID. Sorry for my unclear question! I've tried something like: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/appInfoBox.xml?id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /App/makeInfoBox/%1 [QSA,R=302]`